# F# - convert Array to list

Tags: arrays, list, f#

I am reading a file into an array like follows (note I know this is bad code):

```
let filename = if argv.[0] != null then argv.[0] else System.Console.ReadLine()
let data = File.ReadAllLines(filename)
```

I want to perform an F# `map` onto the data returned in that above line. My problem is that I can only perform `map` on n F# list, and not the `System.String[]` that `File.ReadAllLines()` returns. Can I convert a standard .Net array into an F# list. I'm sure that I could just read the file differently, or labor through manually copying the array contents to a list, but it would be a lot easier if there was a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `Array.toList` to do that.

```
let data2 = data |> Array.toList
```

Or you can use `List.ofArray`

```
let data2 = data |> List.ofArray
```

You can also do `Array.map` instead of `List.map` and in that case you might not need to map to `list` at all.

Comment: The other name for the `Array.toList` function is `List.ofArray`. I never know which one to pick :)

Comment: @TomasPetricek Added! I knew there was something on `List` module, but wasn't sure what exactly the method is (I though it was `fromArray`... ). Thanks!

Comment: @TomasPetricek I prefer the convention of always using `List.ofArray` and the equivalent form function for other types, I think it makes it visually more apparent, especially at a quick glance, that a type-changing operation is underway, especially when it follows a series of piped functions on another type.

Answer (score 2):

Since `File.ReadAllLines` returns an array, you can use [`Array.map`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353512.aspx) on it. It works the same way as `List.map`.

Another option is [`Seq.map`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370346.aspx), since arrays also implement the `seq 'a` (`IEnumerable<T>`) interface.

As others have pointed out, you can also convert the array to a list using `Array.toList` or `List.ofArray`, but be aware that this operation traverses the array and copies it to a list (hence there's a small overhead involved in doing so).

Comment: Is there any sort of difference between `Array.map` and `Seq.map` performance wise?